# I need to replace a particular string which should not have any pre and post string in the line using c# regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Need to replace a string which shouldn't have append with any string in pre or post.
Example:

```
Line 1: migration := '0';
Line 2: ;
```

Here I need to replace the character ';' with '/' in Line number 2 not in Line 1.
Output:

```
Line 1: migration := '0';
Line 2: /
```

I tried to use replace() method using c#. it doesn't work for me. Kindly help on this.

Comment: use regexp, pattern: `^;$`
You can check how it works here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    String originalString = "<your string>";
    String[] splittedString = originalString.Split("\n");
    String lastLine = splittedString[splittedString.Length-1];
    splittedString[splittedString.Length-1] = lastLine.Replace(@";",@"/");
    String desireString = string.Join("\n", splittedString);
```